# MYSQL - Select selecting rows where another column equals something

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
select  feature_requests.*,
from    feature_requests
where   feature_requests.status in ('open','closed','indevelopment')
```

I also have another status - denied.

I need to also select all rows with status denied but another column on my features request table must equal something.

So something that does this:

```
select  feature_requests.*,
from    feature_requests
where   feature_requests.status in ('open','closed','indevelopment','denied') and
        if status = denied, instance_id = ?
```

Not sure of the correct syntax. Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WHERE clause is the correct place to put these kind of conditions, but with a few differences:

```
SELECT  `fr`.*
FROM    `feature_requests` fr
WHERE   (`fr`.`status` IN ('open','closed','indevelopment')) OR
        ((`fr`.`status` = 'denied') AND (`fr`.`instance_id` = ?))
```

P.S - Notice I'm using an alias for `feature_requests` called `fr` instead of writing the whole name again and again. And You don't have to write its name at all because you're using only one table in your query, but I would still use it because it reduces the chances of future mistakes.

For further reading - [SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Also need to remove that `,` on the first line

Comment: @mattjv Notice that you added a redundant `comma` on your first line. This was making a syntax error.

Comment: @itay This query is part of a join query hence the table names and the commas. Was bad copy paste when removing unrelated content on my behalf

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT
  feature_requests.*
FROM
  feature_requests
WHERE
  feature_requests.status IN ('open','closed','indevelopment') OR (
    feature_requests.status='denied' AND
    instance_id=?
  )
```

This can also be written without listing the table name over and over if it is the only table that you are using like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  feature_requests
WHERE
  status IN ('open','closed','indevelopment') OR (
    status='denied' AND
    instance_id=?
  )
```

When using `AND` and/or `OR` in your where clause please also remember to use parenthesis `(` `)` to show your actual meaning even when you know what takes precedence between the `AND` and `OR`. [For more information on precedence of operators with MySQl](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) Example:

```
color=blue AND shape=circle OR type=ball
```

means

```
(color=blue AND shape=cirlce) OR type=ball
```

but could easily be misinterpreted as

```
color=blue AND (shape=circle OR type=ball)
```

Answer (score 0):

From rusty memory, you're probably wanting something like this

```
SELECT feature_requests.* FROM feature_requests 
WHERE feature_requests.status IN ('open', 'closed', 'indevelopment') OR
  (feature_requests.status='denied' AND instance_id = ???)
```

What you have right now is pretty close.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-and-or-clauses.htm